# Python try/except ... function always returns false

Tags: python, pylons

I'm trying to figure out the problem in this short paragraph of code.  Any help would be appreciated.  Regardless of what I specify User.email to be, it always returns false.

```
def add(self):

    #1 -- VALIDATE EMAIL ADDRESS
    #Check that e-mail has been completed
    try:
        #Validate if e-mail address is in correct format
        if (isAddressValid(self.email) == 0):
            self.errors['email'] = 'You have entered an invalid e-mail address';
            return 0

    except NameError:
        self.errors['email'] = 'Please enter your e-mail'
        return 0

>>> u = User()
>>> u.email = 'test@example.com'
>>> u.add()
0
>>> print u.errors
{'email': 'Please enter your e-mail'}
```

I have confirmed that the false being returned is coming from except NameError.

Also, isAddressValid() is just a method to check the structure of an e-mail address.

Thanks.

Comment: SO `isAddressValid` is always throwing a `NameError`, right? You should fix the problem as others have described below, but the real problem is in `isAddressValid`.

Comment: Yes, it was such a simple problem.  I forgot to put self.isAddressValid()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't included a `return` statement for the positive case...  Also, when a function doesn't include a `return` statement, the caller receives `None` instead...

```
def add(self):

    #1 -- VALIDATE EMAIL ADDRESS
    #Check that e-mail has been completed
    try:
        #Validate if e-mail address is in correct format
        if (isAddressValid(self.email) == 0):
            self.errors['email'] = 'You have entered an invalid e-mail address';
            return False

    except NameError:
        self.errors['email'] = 'Please enter your e-mail'
        return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have two values.

- `0`
- `None`

If you print the value instead of using it in an if-statement, you'll see the two conditions.  Consider adding print statements to see what the value actually is.

```
if (isAddressValid(self.email) == 0):
```

If this is True, you get `0`.

If this is False, you'll get `None`.

And the exception give `0`.

Comment: @ensnare: I mean ADD PRINT STATEMENTS.  See what the values are.  I mean that your if-statement is incomplete.  If you ADD PRINT STATEMENTS, you'll see how it's incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

If I were re-writing this code, I would go for something like this:

```
def add(self):
    try:
        if not isAddressValid(self.email):
            self.errors['email'] = 'You have entered an invalid e-mail address';
    except NameError:
        self.errors['email'] = 'Please enter your e-mail'
    return 'email' not in self.errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what problem you are talking about , but you are always returning 0

Try  adding an else clause for the case of the Valid Email (which you are currently not considering)

```
def add(self):

#1 -- VALIDATE EMAIL ADDRESS
#Check that e-mail has been completed
try:
    #Validate if e-mail address is in correct format
    if (isAddressValid(self.email) == 0):
        self.errors['email'] = 'You have entered an invalid e-mail address';
        return 0
    else
        return 1

except NameError:
    self.errors['email'] = 'Please enter your e-mail'
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You said `isAddressValid` is a method, right? Since `add` is also a method, perhaps you have to prepend a `self.`:

```
if (self.isAddressValid(self.email) == 0):
```

This most probably will deal with your `NameError`.

After that, add an `else` clause when the check succeeds:

```
    …
    self.errors['email'] = 'You have entered an invalid e-mail address'
    return 0
else:
    return 1
```